# Can an ARRAYFORMULA be used for grouped RANK?

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am not able to use `RANK` in grouped rows within an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

I have a big dataset (≈100.000 rows) where I want to create an `ARRAYFORMULA` that makes a different `RANK` for the rows that share the same identifier.

Although I get the result without problems dragging a formula (combining `RANK` and `FILTER`), I am not able to replicate the result with an `ARRAYFORMULA`. [This file with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H_Vedq40JUZfdgSslxoAc_C25QfOnPpKASpTUOXiivk/edit?usp=sharing) replicates the problem.

In advance, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with sorting and counting in principle, but it's difficult in practice because the functions you would like to use like Countifs aren't array friendly. Here is a rather long-winded way of doing it where you sort, Vlookup on a combination of Slug and Points, get the matching row number and subtract the row number you get from  a Vlookup just matching on Slug:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",vlookup(A2:A&"|"&B2:B,{sort(A2:A&"|"&B2:B,A2:A,true,B2:B,false),row(A2:A)},2,false)-
vlookup(A2:A,{sort(A2:A,A2:A,true),row(A2:A)},2,false)+1,""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

also solution:

#### US syntax

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"♥"&B2:B, SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")))&"♥"&
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A, B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0.00000001)}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0)=1, 
 ROUNDDOWN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A, B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0.00000001)}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "limit 0", 1), 0), ))
 ,,999^99)), " ")&"♠"&transpose(SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A, B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0.00000001)}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0)=1, 
 ROUNDDOWN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A, B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0.00000001)}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "limit 0", 1), 0), ))
 ,,999^99)), " ")))), 1, 0))),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"), 2, 1), 2, 0)))
```

#### EU syntax:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"♥"&B2:B; SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")))&"♥"&
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A\ B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0,00000001)}; 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "offset 1"; 0)=1; 
 ROUNDDOWN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A\ B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0,00000001)}; 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "limit 0"; 1); 0); ))
 ;;999^99)); " ")&"♠"&transpose(SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A\ B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0,00000001)}; 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "offset 1"; 0)=1; 
 ROUNDDOWN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A\ B2:B+(ROW(B2:B)*0,00000001)}; 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "limit 0"; 1); 0); ))
 ;;999^99)); " ")))); 1; 0)));;999^99));;999^99); "♦")); "♠"); 2; 1); 2; 0)))
```

[image]